# Posicionar todos os selects no índice 0 com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Bom dia!

Estou com uma dúvida, e gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar.
Tenho dois `selects` na minha página. Tenho um botão para cadastrar um novo registro e outro para editar cada registro.
Quando clico no editar, ele abre um modal que contém as informações daquele registro. Se, em seguida, eu clicar no botão "Novo Cadastro", ele continua deixando os `selects` com as informações do ultimo registro.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Abaixo, o código do modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-edit-veiculo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-edit-veiculo-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80% !important;">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Fechar</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-edit-veiculo-label">Novo Veículo</h4>
            </div><!-- modal header -->

            <div class="modal-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="unidade-veiculo">Unidade</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select class="form-control modal-detalhe-veiculo-unidade-veiculo" name="unidade-veiculo">
                                    <option>Selecione uma Unidade</option>
                                    <option value="001S000000nlKu4IAE">Teste 2</option>
                                    <option value="001S000000nmTBdIAM">Inpulso 04</option>
                                    <option value="001S000000nm2EiIAI">Teste Inpulso 8</option>
                                    <option value="001S000000nm2deIAA">Teste Inpulso 10</option>
                                    <option value="001S000000nm2fGIAQ">Teste Inpulso 14</option>
                                    <option value="001S000000kHf7lIAC">RMR COMERCIO E TRANSPORTE DE GAS LTDA.</option>
                                    <option value="001S000000nJfoyIAC">Santos</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="placa">Placa</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control modal-detalhe-veiculo-placa-veiculo" name="placa" placeholder="Placa"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="tipo-veiculo">Tipo de Veículo</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select class="form-control modal-detalhe-veiculo-tipo-veiculo" name="tipo-veiculo">
                                    <option>Selecione um Tipo de veículo</option>
                                    <option value="a1vS0000000CLYkIAO">Caminhonete</option>
                                    <option value="a1vS0000000CLYpIAO">Triciclo</option>
                                    <option value="a1vS0000000CLYfIAO">Pick-Up</option>
                                    <option value="a1vS0000000CLYuIAO">Caminhão</option>
                                    <option value="a1vS0000000CLYzIAO">Moto</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="descricao-veiculo">Descrição</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control  modal-detalhe-veiculo-descricao-veiculo" name="descricao-veiculo" placeholder="Descrição"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btn-salvar-veiculo">Gravar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Abaixo, o botão que abre a modal:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="border: 1px">
            <div id="" class="col-xs-12 " align="right">
                <button id="btn-novo-veiculo" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Cadastro</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

a função para limpar os campos:

```
function clearModal(){
            j$('#modal-edit-veiculo .modal-body input').val('');
        }
```

Os `inputs` estão sendo limpos, agora preciso posicionar os `selects` no índice 0 quando clicar no botão.

Comment: Amigo explique melhor a sua dúvida, se possível poste um código de um exemplo do que está tentando fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua função `clearModal()`, adicione a seguinte linha:

```
j$('#modal-edit-veiculo .modal-body select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Ficando assim:

```
function clearModal() {
    j$('#modal-edit-veiculo .modal-body input').val('');
    j$('#modal-edit-veiculo .modal-body select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo71a32v/). [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445661/1267304).

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava!

Answer (score 0):

Uma vêz que tens esses `input` e `select` numa `<form>` **o melhor era fazer** `form.reset();`...

```
document.querySelector('form').reset();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xm37qbfh/